# how to require and check url parameters in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a way in your routes file to check and validate URL parameters. I am NOT talking about restful '/controller/action/:id' params, but 'controller/action?param1=x&param2=y&param3=z'. I need to be able to validate each parameter and require them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can. For example to check that param1 exists and is not blank you would do the following:

```
match 'c/action' => 'c#action', :constraints => lambda{ |req| !req.params[:param1].blank? }
```

You can also scope these constraints to apply them to multiple routes:

```
scope :constraints => lambda{ |req| !req.params[:param1].blank? } do
  match 'controller/action1' => 'controller#action1'
  match 'controller/action2' => 'controller#action2'
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with constraints approach outlined by Pan Thomakos is that it will prevent the url with invalid set of parameters from ever reaching your codebase and you being able to respond to the user in a meaningful manner(the user will see page not found error I believe).

If that satisfies your requirement, thats fine, but a more user-friendly way would be to move parameter validation into the corresponding controller where in your action method you would go through the set of params this action method has received and if any of the required are missing, you would construct a meaningull message and error it back to the user via a:notice

Comment: Actually it works perfectly, the user should never be able to access the page without the passed params. The url is generated out of another system and is transparent to the user. This is a very specific and odd case.